# Can't Import Specific Excel Range into Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

Please can someone check over the following piece of code as I can't see why the named range is not being imported.  Instead the full spreadsheet is coming into the database.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "EAST OF ENGLAND", fle.Path, True, "Tasking Records!A:V"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the 'Range' option.  See below:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "EAST OF ENGLAND", fle.Path, True, Range:="Tasking Records!A:V"
```